# Projection of a point to a plane

Tags: geometry

I have the plane $x+2y+3z+4=0$
and the point $M(1,1,1)$ and I need to find the projection of that point to the plane

I have calculated the distance but I don't know how to proceed any thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean the position of the foot of the perpendicular?

Comment: the point that the perpendicular passes through the plane i suppose

Comment: Write down the equation of the line through $M$ which is perpendicular to the plane and solve simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula to find the foot of perpendicular $(A,B,C)$ of a point $(h,k,l)$ onto a plane $ax+by+cz+d=0$ is $\frac{A-h}{a}=\frac{B-k}{b}=\frac{C-l}{c}=-\left(\frac{ah+bk+cl+d}{a^2+b^2+c^2}\right)$

So in your case, $a=1$ , $b=2$,  $c=3$, $d=4$ and $h=1$, $k=1$, $l=1$

#Also (OR) pointed in comments by @David Quinn, solve the plane and the line to get the point of intersection, the line can be created using point M and the normal vector of the plane aka $(1,2,3)$.

[image]